# Передавать ли $_POST явно?

Tags: php, post

Можно сделать

```
$checker = new Validate;
$result= $checker ->checkerForm($_POST);
```

А можно просто

```
$result= $checker ->checkerForm(); // аргумент не указан
```

Ведь внутри себя checkerForm сможет обратиться к суперглобальному `$_POST`, поверить его и выдать необходимый ответ.

Сам думаю порешать по первому варианту т.к. другим кодерам явно будет видно с чем именно работает checkerForm внутри себя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если сделаешь без передачи аргумента то функция будет зависима от $_POST, а если со временем у тебя $_POST будет где нибудь фильтроваться или ты от него избавишься и будешь юзать какую нибудь другую логику для получения пришедших данных (например Input::get())? Лучше передавай данные аргументом))

Comment: Да, об этом не подумал, спасибо